# Error Trigger AFTER DELETE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, trigger

tengo el siguiente código:

```
create or replace trigger calckmdl
after delete on tsegmento
for each row
declare
    total rutas.km%type;
begin
if deleting then
    select km into total from rutas where ruta=:new.ruta;
        if :old.unidad = 'km' then
            total:=total-:old.distancia;
            end if;
        else if :old.unidad = 'm' then
            total:=total-:old.distancia/1000;
        end if;
    update rutas set km=total where ruta=:new.ruta;
end if
```

Cuando hago un DELETE, siempre me salta el error *"No data found"*. Llevo semanas rompiéndome la cabeza, no entiendo cuál es el problema.
Tengo un trigger para INSERT y UPDATE del mismo estilo y funcionan perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que deberías hacer siempre que hagas unas select como la estás haciendo es controlar las excepciones. Si no las quieres tratar al menos poner un NULL en la excepción others.

```
BEGIN
   select km into total from rutas where ruta=:new.ruta;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
END;
```

Si el trigger es after delete sólo va a entrar cuando hagas un delete, por lo que la comprobación del primer if es redundante.

Si estas borrando deberías usar :old.ruta en la select, ¿no?, no hay ningún valor nuevo en un borrado.

Después veo que tienes un END IF después de la asignacion TOTAL := TOTAL - :OLD.DISTANCIA; por lo que el IF :OLD.UNIDAD = 'm' THEN pertenece al else del IF principal, no al de la comprobación de la unidad, por lo que nunca entaría en esa parte.

A ver si lo que te he dicho te sirve

Comment: Mil gracias, los errores del if están porque lo copié mal de un trigger conjunto. El problema estaba en el SELECT y en el UPDATE, que como dices debía de usar :OLD en vez de :NEW